# Passing (commandline?) arguments to a Matlab script

Tags: matlab, function, command-line, parameters

just a really quick question.

I've been given this file, and I'd like to run it.

I believe it requires command-line arguments to function with `function trees_main(puzzle_ind,print_f,nls)` but I'm not sure. It's part of a few different files - but this is the main controller.

Any ideas on how to pass the function some parameters? Is it done at runtime?

```
    % A* search tree algorithm for solving 8 puzzle problem
    % Inputs:
    %   puzzle_ind = 1:30
    %   print_f = 0/1, 1 to show the step solutions 
    %   nls = 0/1, 1 to Nilsson Score
    % Calls: 
    %   trees (A* search)
    %   trees_gm (Generate moves)
    %   trees_mh (Manhattan metrics)
    %   trees_nls (Nilsson sequence)
    % Uses:
    %   combinations.mat (30 resolvable puzzle combinations)
    %

    function trees_main(puzzle_ind,print_f,nls)

    global Tg T0 T1 nls_f % These variables are visible in all functions
    nls_f = nls;
    Tg = [1 2 3; 8 0 4; 7 6 5]; % Goal sequence
    % Coordinates (row and column) of tiles in a puzzle
    T0 = [1 1; 1 2; 1 3; 2 1; 2 2; 2 3; 3 1; 3 2; 3 3]; 
    T1 = [1 2 3 8 0 4 7 6 5];
    load combinations Cmb

    if puzzle_ind >= 1 && puzzle_ind <= 30 
      P = Cmb{puzzle_ind};  % assign the Puzzle
      [T,n1,n2] = trees(P,print_f); % call A* search function
      fprintf('\nPuzzle:\n')
      fprintf('% 1i %1i %1i\n',Cmb{puzzle_ind}')
      fprintf('Solution:\n')
      fprintf('% 1i %1i %1i\n',T') 
      fprintf('Number of nodes = %4i\nNumber of moves = %2i\n\n',n1,n2)
    end
    trees_plot(puzzle_ind); % statistics
    return

    function trees_plot(pind)
    global N1 nls_f
    M = (N1(:,[2 8])');
    n = size(M,2);
    plot(1:n,M)
    xlabel('Number of Tested Nodes')
    ylabel('Metrics (without cost)')
    if nls_f == 0
      s1 = 'No';
    else
      s1 = 'Yes';
    end
    title(sprintf('Puzzle Index %2i, NSS %s',pind,s1))
    axis([1 n 0 max(M(1,:))+1])
    grid on
    text(5,15,'Level (Cost)')
    return
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Did you search the internet for this at all? MATLAB has great documentation and this is a very basic question.

Comment: See: [function basics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-basics.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run this function **trees_main(puzzle_ind,print_f,nls)** from matlab command line, then it should be saved with file name **trees_main.m** on your matlab path. You can use **addpath('some path')** where this file (trees_main.m) reside. Now, you are all set to call from command window. Just call like normal function call. **For example, trees_main(15, 1, 1).**